# How to set minimum/maximum value to an Integer variable

Tags: go

Like in Java we initialise variable to minimum/maximum,

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Is there any way to do in Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution .

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    // Few Examples

    // Integer Max
    fmt.Printf("Max int64 = %v\n", math.MaxInt64)
    fmt.Printf("Max int32 = %v\n", math.MaxInt32)
    fmt.Printf("Max int16 = %v\n", math.MaxInt16)

    // Integer Min
    fmt.Printf("Min int64 = %v\n", math.MinInt64)
    fmt.Printf("Min int32 = %v\n", math.MinInt32)

    // Float
    fmt.Printf("Max flloat64= %v\n", math.MaxFloat64)
    fmt.Printf("Max float32= %v\n", math.MaxFloat32)

}
```

Answer (score 13):

They are available in math package:

> Integer limit values.
>
> ```
> const (
>     MaxInt8   = 1<<7 - 1
>     MinInt8   = -1 << 7
>     MaxInt16  = 1<<15 - 1
>     MinInt16  = -1 << 15
>     MaxInt32  = 1<<31 - 1
>     MinInt32  = -1 << 31
>     MaxInt64  = 1<<63 - 1
>     MinInt64  = -1 << 63
>     MaxUint8  = 1<<8 - 1
>     MaxUint16 = 1<<16 - 1
>     MaxUint32 = 1<<32 - 1
>     MaxUint64 = 1<<64 - 1
> )
> ```

https://golang.org/pkg/math/#pkg-constants